# Bat file list file names

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Hi everyone im trying to create a .bat file that would list all the files in each folder and add some text after each line into a txt file like something like this

```
f(1).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
f(2).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
f(3).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
f(4).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
f(5).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
f(6).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
f(7).bmp 1 1 1 100 100
```

the **1 1 1 100 100** after each line will always remain the same, so far i have...
`dir /b *.bmp >infofile.txt` which lists each file but how do i add the numbers after. thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
break > infofile.txt
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s *.bmp') do (
   echo %%F 1 1 1 100 100 >>infofile.txt 
)
```

Comment: beat me to it - note the %% is valid when running in a `.bat`, but use a single % on the command line - and the /s will give you file from subdirs as well as the path in the filename

Comment: Thanks npocmaka and akf but ive copied the code exactly, but it only lists just one file.. the txt file only contains C:\Users\Charles\t\t\positive\rawdata\f(99).bmp 1 1 1 100 100.... i have over 300 files in the folder

Comment: oops.You need two `>s`.Its now fixed.

Comment: `>>infofile.txt echo %%F 1 1 1 100 100` <--- if you use this syntax then it will not add a trailing space to the end of each line.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off
(for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /s *.bmp') do (
   echo %%F 1 1 1 100 100
))>infofile.txt
```